# Как объединить два проекта, frontend и backend в один, чтобы разворачивать на сервере одним файлом

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, spring-boot, развертывание

Есть два проекта: на Vue js - фронт. Разворачивается на http://localhost:8081
Второй - бэк, на Java Spring boot API. Разворачивается на http://localhost:8080. Общение между бэком и фронтом происходит с помощью JSON.

Можно ли (и если да, то что почитать) сделать что-то вроде контейнера для этих двух проектом, чтобы задеплоить на сервер одним файлом?

Comment: Наверное вам Docker нужен

Comment: рассматривал его, как вариант, но нужен другой способ, если он существует. Докер не подойдет

Comment: Почему не подойдёт? Вроде бы это стандартное и общепринятое решение вашей залачи

Comment: Если докер не годится, то укажите хотя бы на каких ОС нужно чтоб развертывание работало

Comment: тут больше речь про сборку проекта в один jar/ear/war

Comment: можно переложить файлы фронтенда после его сборки в папку ресурсов бекенда, в итоге будет 1 файл (или плагином мавена собирать фронтенд и подкладывать его в бекенд). Можно еще использовать аналог webjars, но тут сложнее, будет путаница без автоматизации. [Один из примеров](https://auth0.com/blog/integrating-node-dot-js-build-tools-with-maven/)